# WebSocket In/OutBoundChannel 'clientSession' has not been established. Consider to 'start' this container

Tags: spring-integration, spring-websocket

I'm using spring-integration-websocket for using stompSubProtocol.

My Sample code is 'https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/tree/master/spring-integration-websocket/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/websocket'

My code almost same sample code.
but.. My code cause below error ..

```
"clientOutboundChannel-1" org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.websocket.outbound.WebSocketOutboundMessageHandler#1]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 'clientSession' has not been established. Consider to 'start' this container.
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:84)
```

I set int-websocket in/out-bound-channel at xml.

```
    <beans:bean id="webSocketClient" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="org.springframework.web.socket.client.WebSocketClient"></beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>

    <int-websocket:client-container id="clientWebSocketContainer"
                                client="webSocketClient"
                                uri="*"
                                uri-variables="ws,user"
                                send-buffer-size-limit="1000000"
                                send-time-limit="100"
                                origin="FOO"
                                phase="100">
</int-websocket:client-container>

<beans:bean id="stompSubProtocolHandler" class="org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.StompSubProtocolHandler">

   </beans:bean>

   <beans:bean id="passThruSubProtocolHandler"
      class="org.springframework.integration.websocket.support.PassThruSubProtocolHandler" >
      </beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="simpleMessageConverter"
      class="org.springframework.integration.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter" > </beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="mapMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.integration.support.converter.MapMessageConverter"> </beans:bean> 


<int-websocket:inbound-channel-adapter id="customInboundAdapter" container="clientWebSocketContainer"
                                       auto-startup="false"
                                       payload-type="java.lang.Integer"
                                       protocol-handlers="passThruSubProtocolHandler"
                                       default-protocol-handler="stompSubProtocolHandler"
                                       message-converters="simpleMessageConverter,mapMessageConverter"
                                       merge-with-default-converters="true"
                                       channel="clientInboundChannel"
                                       error-channel="errorChannel"
                                       send-timeout="2000"
                                       phase="200" />
```

```
<int-websocket:outbound-channel-adapter id="defaultOutboundAdapter" container="serverWebSocketContainer" />

<int-websocket:outbound-channel-adapter id="customOutboundAdapter" container="clientWebSocketContainer"
                                        default-protocol-handler="stompSubProtocolHandler"
                                        protocol-handlers="passThruSubProtocolHandler"
                                        message-converters="simpleMessageConverter,mapMessageConverter"
                                        merge-with-default-converters="true"
                                        channel="clientOutboundChannel" />

<int:channel id="clientOutboundChannel" />
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem that your mock `webSocketClient` doesn't return a `Session` object. So, container considers that as a fatal issue and fail.